# Null Values Issue by Streaming with Spark and Kafka

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spark-structured-streaming

I created SparkConsumer so I can send a csv file to Kafka through Spark Structured Streaming. I start the sparkConsumer then he waits for the Producer. I start the Producer and the file is sent. The Problem is that I become a 'null'-values in a dataframe and not the content. 
My output looks like this:

```
-------------------------------------------
Batch: 1
-------------------------------------------
+---------+---------+-----------+--------+-----------------------+
|InvoiceNo|StockCode|Description|Quantity|timestamp              |
+---------+---------+-----------+--------+-----------------------+
|null     |null     |null       |null    |2019-01-08 15:46:29.156|
|null     |null     |null       |null    |2019-01-08 15:46:29.224|
|null     |null     |null       |null    |2019-01-08 15:46:29.224|
|null     |null     |null       |null    |2019-01-08 15:46:29.225|
|null     |null     |null       |null    |2019-01-08 15:46:29.225|
|null     |null     |null       |null    |2019-01-08 15:46:29.225|
|null     |null     |null       |null    |2019-01-08 15:46:29.225|
|null     |null     |null       |null    |2019-01-08 15:46:29.225|
|null     |null     |null       |null    |2019-01-08 15:46:29.225|
|null     |null     |null       |null    |2019-01-08 15:46:29.225|
|null     |null     |null       |null    |2019-01-08 15:46:29.225|
|null     |null     |null       |null    |2019-01-08 15:46:29.241|
|null     |null     |null       |null    |2019-01-08 15:46:29.241|
|null     |null     |null       |null    |2019-01-08 15:46:29.241|
|null     |null     |null       |null    |2019-01-08 15:46:29.241|
|null     |null     |null       |null    |2019-01-08 15:46:29.241|
|null     |null     |null       |null    |2019-01-08 15:46:29.241|
|null     |null     |null       |null    |2019-01-08 15:46:29.241|
|null     |null     |null       |null    |2019-01-08 15:46:29.241|
|null     |null     |null       |null    |2019-01-08 15:46:29.241|
+---------+---------+-----------+--------+-----------------------+
```

The Code for sparkConsumer is:

```
object sparkConsumer extends App {

  val rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger()
  rootLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR)

  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("Spark-Kafka-Integration")
    .master("local")
    .getOrCreate()

  val schema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("InvoiceNo", StringType, nullable = true),
    StructField("StockCode", StringType, nullable = true),
    StructField("Description", StringType, nullable = true),
    StructField("Quantity", StringType, nullable = true)
  ))

  import spark.implicits._
  val df = spark
    .readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    .option("subscribe", "test")
    .option("delimiter", ";")
    .option("header","true")
    .option("inferSchema","true")
    .load()

  val df1 = df.selectExpr("CAST(value as STRING)", "CAST(timestamp AS TIMESTAMP)").as[(String, Timestamp)]
    .select(from_json($"value", schema).as("data"), $"timestamp")
    .select("data.*", "timestamp")


  df1.writeStream
    .format("console")
    .option("truncate","false")
    .start()
    .awaitTermination()

}
```

Producer.scala:

```
object Producer extends App {
  import java.util.Properties
  import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer._

  val  props = new Properties()
  props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")                                             
  props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")        
  props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")      

  val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)                                             
  val TOPIC="test"
  val fileName = "path/to/test.csv"
  val lines = Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines()

  for(i <- lines){
    val record = new ProducerRecord(TOPIC, "key", s"$i")                    
    producer.send(record)
  }
  val record = new ProducerRecord(TOPIC, "key", "the end "+new java.util.Date)
  producer.send(record)
  producer.close()

}
```

Can anyone help me to become the content of my file?

Comment: Could you past code of your producer app? and check content of topic `galena_test`

Comment: See my update.
What do you meen with the conten of the topic?

Comment: check with some consumer the content of topic, ex. you can use: `./kafka/kafka-console-consumer.sh --property print.key=true --property key.separator="-" --from-beginning --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic TOPIC_NAME`

Comment: I have a similar problem. I used from_csv instead as the string is a csv message with a header. The message arrives with data. I can see that because a use a custom deserializer udf.   It has been a few years, but how did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is related with serialization and deserialization.
Your `value`, that you write to the topic is in csv format, ex:

`111,someCode,someDescription,11`

Your *Spark consumer*, thinks that message is in json format (`from_json` with some schema). If message will be something like below, parsing would work.

```
{
    "InvoiceNo": "111",
    "StockCode": "someCode",
    "Description": "someDescription",
    "Quantity": "11"
}
```

You have to change serializing or deserializing to match each other.

One of following option should work

1. Producer has to write message to topic in json format
2. Spark consumer should parse line using `comma` to split fields

Answer (score 0):

In my case deleting `.option("delimiter", ";")` works